# Dailymotion API Browser session

Tags: javascript, oauth, dailymotion-api

I have the following code

```
 DM.init({apiKey: 'my key', status: true, cookie: true});

    function Login_DM(callback)
    {
        DM.login(function(response)
                {
            if (response.session)
            {
                //getScreenName_DM();
                callback();

            }
            else
            {
                // user is not logged in
            }
                }, {scope: 'read write'});


    }
```

Even though 'cookie' is set to true, when I refresh the browser it asks me to enter the credentials everytime.

## Edit

After Erisu's reply, I did the following

```
function Login_DM(callback)
{

    DM.getLoginStatus(function(response)
            {
                if (response.session)
                {
                    // logged in and connected user, someone you know
                    callback(null);
                }
                else
                {
                    DM.login(function(response)
                            {
                        if (response.session)
                        {
                            //getScreenName_DM();
                            callback();

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // user is not logged in
                        }
                            }, {scope: 'read write'});
                }
            });

}
```

The above still doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the Login_DM function is called only when the user's login status is not available.  I was able to reproduce the same issue with the provided code sample only if I immediately called the Login_DM function without applying a login status check.

**Example Login Status Check:**

```
DM.getLoginStatus(function(response)
{
    if (response.session)
    {
        // logged in and connected user, someone you know
    }
    else
    {
        // no user session available, someone you dont know
        Login_DM();
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried the above as shown in the edit, but it still doesnt work

Comment: Using the modified code still works for me.  What browser are you using?  Is the browser configured to accept cookies?  Is there any software that blocks cookies?  Even if the cookie setting in the DM.init is set to true, it still relies on the browser to accept them.

Comment: I am using Chrome. I have integrated other services like Youtube and Facebook which work just fine in the same browser. I am a little confused now.